# start an intent using actions on broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

what i am trying to do is to start my app when the headset (plug in) in my android mobile here is my code , but nothing happens :

```
public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         context.startService(new Intent(context, TestService.class));
         Intent newIntent = new Intent(".android.intent.action.MAIN"); 
         context.startActivity(newIntent); 
    }

}
```

and here is the **manifest** :

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.talktome.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".BootBroadcast">   
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"/>   
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

please any suggestions???

Comment: anything interesting in logcat?

Comment: nop !! nothing at all ..

Comment: try to add `Lod.d(...)` call at the `onReceive` method. Do you see it in logcat?

Comment: here is what happens after i edit my code : java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG flg=0x10000000 (has extras) } in com.example.talktome.fucnction.BootBroadcast@416d4dd8 –

Comment: : Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=.com.example.talktome.HomeScreen }

Comment: what `HomeScreen` is? it's not listed in your question

Comment: it's the main activity that i called onResume on it : @Override
  public void onResume() {
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
      registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
      super.onResume();
  }

Comment: there is no need to register receiver programmatically if it's already declared at the `Manifest`. please think about the structure of the app

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this snippet in your current activity?

```
IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    BootBroadcast receiver = new BootBroadcast();
    registerReceiver(receiver, receiverFilter);
```

Also add this flag inside BootBroadcast class

```
newIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Add this in the manifest for second activity

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.talktome.TestService"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: yes i did but now it's give me something else .. it crash and the logcat says : Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=.com.example.talktome.HomeScreen }

Comment: yes sure i did but it gives me the following logcat

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG flg=0x10000000 (has extras) } in com.example.talktome.fucnction.BootBroadcast@416d4dd8